# Change price with modifier, instead of + add to price

Tags: expresso-store

I have a gift card that I'm including in my store, and I would like to have the total price change with a modifier, instead of adding a dollar amount to a base price. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be have a base price of $0 then enter the total amount for each modifier so the price is adjusted accordingly.