# Set price with product modifiers (not + or -)

Tags: expresso-store

I sell a product that the customer can either pay full price, or pay a down payment and then (outside of EE) make payments.

What I'd like is to have options/modifiers:

- "Full price" = (no price adjustment)
- "Down payment" = (set price to $100)

Is this possible without having to manually calculate {price}-x="Down Payment"?  From what I can tell, I can only add or subject from {price}.

I read this: [Change price with modifier, instead of + add to price](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14089/change-price-with-modifier-instead-of-add-to-price), however that would break sorting/searching by price since Store would consider them all to cost $0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative price modifiers to adjust your products final price.

So lets say you have a $1200 item that you would create a product with a price of $1200 then you would need to create 2 modifier options 'Full Price' with out adding a modifier value and 'Down Payment' with a value of -1100 as the modifier value.

This would allow you to still sort by price but you would need to do the math to get the value.

Another option seems like a bit overkill in your situation but would be possible. You could create a new channel with a Store Field and a relationship field. Once you have done that you would be able to create your product in the main product channel with the normal price. Then you would create another entry in the newly created channel with the down payment price and then you would need to relate the down payment product to the entry you just created.

This can add a lot of overhead and really provides a less then ideal publishing approach for your content creators.

The final option would be to create an extension that would automatically calculate the difference for you.

Comment: Thanks. Essentially the reason I can't to use the negative modifier, is because the down payment needs to be a static amount, unaffected by sales/discounts.  On the Expresso site it says "Complex Variations - you can template your own custom modifiers." so I guess I was expecting more.

Might have to give CartThrob a try I guess, it seems to be able to do this out of the box.

Comment: You can do modifiers like that with front end templates but they won't be able to affect the price since they are basically text modifiers. Also discounts would be applied at the product level so you would still have to differentiate the regular price from the down payment product anyways.